# Simple News Feeds: Without Server-Side Languages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a news feed that I update periodically. I currently have the website regenerate the page based on a text file that just contains the title and text for that news update, using Python. Example:

> 1.This is a Title
>
> This is some text that represents the news for today, etc. etc. I'm
> just typing things at this point to make this look like a paragraph.
>
> 2.This is a Title, Too
>
> This is some text that represents the news for today, etc. etc. I'm
> just typing things at this point to make this look like a paragraph.

Is there a more elegant way to do this with some non PHP/server-side language?

Comment: maybe using xml with javascript?

Comment: Do you have any more specific advice?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS

Comment: I'm not looking for a ticker. I just want a method of turning a txt with a list of news headlines and paragraphs into a "content" section of a website. I'm currently using Python, but there's got to be something more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

have a look @ xml-parsing:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

The idea is as follows:

- You first create an XML file which is your "news feed"
- You then create an html page which uses javascript to parse the xmlfile and load it into DOM
- You output the contents of the file

but why, if you are already using python, not create / read an xml file with python? or dynamically generate the file with python?

Comment: Thanks for the tip--I'll look into it. I'm trying to find the most elegant solution. While the Python method works, I want the project to be very self contained and elegant.

Comment: best of luck, and if you find an elegant solution, share it with us